# TransactionScope Exception In WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, transactionscope, nettcpbinding

I'm trying enble transaction flow in a wcf service.

However I get the following error:

```
  The header 'OleTxTransaction' from the namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/02/tx/oletx' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process. Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.
```

This is a code snippet of the code I'm trying to run:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
                                 {
                                     IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
                                 };

using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
        {
            try
            {
                var company = CreateCompanyDto(settings);

                if (settings.Institution.CompletedSetup)
                {
                    _ezFinanceCompanyServiceLibrary.UpdateCompany(company); // This is the wcf call.
                }
                else
                {
                   _ezFinanceCompanyServiceLibrary.CreateCompany(company); // This is the wcf call.
                    CreateDefaultInventroyItems(company.EntityGuid);
                }

                _db.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Complete();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _log.Error(exception.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

this is my binding options on the web.config of the web api

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBindingbehavior" transactionFlow="true" portSharingEnabled="true" />
  </netTcpBinding>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="netMsmqBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have the Operation contracts on my service interface in the wcf

```
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
int CreateCompany(CompanyDto newCompany);
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
int UpdateCompany(CompanyDto Company);
```

I have the following attribute on my exposed methods

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
```

My bindings options on the App.config in the wcf service

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBinding" transactionFlow="true" portSharingEnabled="true" />
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have enabled the Network DTC access, I allow Inbounnd and Outbound, I have no authentication Required checked.
I have enabled XA Transactions and SNA LU 6.2 Transactions

I have tried adding the following attribute to my bindings:

```
transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
```

on both the service and web api.

Cannot seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there were `[OperationContract]` attributes placed on the methods that were being called by the WCF methods that already had the `[OperationContract]` removing all the `[OperationContract]` attributes and only placing them on the methods exposed by the WCF solved the problem.